# ActiveColleb Webhook - Do not able to retrieve task's hours update

Tags: webhooks, activecollab

I am working with a webhook for ActiveCollab but facing an issue while retrieves hour update in a task.

Got an event as `"type":"TaskUpdated",` while adding hours in a task and request JSON did not have any hours tracking information. It seems like task details only.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right I can confirm this. I guess it is done by design, you have a variety of API's at your disposal: https://gist.github.com/Elvis339/c66104950d0a7801ef544869786d2c77

To preform that action.